# Passing arrays from bash to PHP

Tags: php, bash

Is it possible to do something like this in order to get the output below.

**Bash**

```
myArray='\${array("Red","Green","Blue")};'
echo $myArray
```

**PHP**

```
$ScriptData = "${shell_exec('script.sh')}:"
var_dump($ScriptData);
```

Output:

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "Red" 
    [1]=> string(5) "Green" 
    [2]=> string(4) "Blue" 
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Yes. What's the problem?

Comment: Can I pass the array from bash as a text string and convert it into a PHP array once it gets there?

Comment: I realise I can use explode, but want to see it could work this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use also the '[exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)' function, it returns the output of your script in a array:

```
$output = array();
exec('script.sh', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

But I think that is safer if your shell script output a coma separated list and explode it on the php side:

```
$output = explode(',', shell_exec('script.sh');
```

Comment: Thanks, does this separate them using \n or something similar?

Comment: Yes, you can replace the ',' with a "\n" or even "\r\n" (notice the double quotes) or whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks, this best answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this in PHP

```
$data = shell_exec('path/to/script.sh');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to let the shell script output each entry on a separate line:

```
myArray=(Red Green Blue)
for i in ${myArray[*]}; do
    echo $i
done
```

The run the shell script from PHP using the [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function and pass an array variable as its second argument. Each line of output of the executed command is added to this array, without the trailing newline.

```
$output = array();
exec('script.sh', $output);
print_r($output);
```

It produces exactly the output you posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Easy and robust is to hand over a json encoded array:

```
#!/bin/bash
myArray="'[\"Red\",\"Green\",\"Blue\"]'"
php -r "var_dump(json_decode($myArray));";
```

The output of that is:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "Red"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Green"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "Blue"
}
```

Comment: Cool, this is likely possible with Associative and multidimensional arrays too then. I'll have a look, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

can also using `eval`

```
myArray='$data = array("Red","Green","Blue");'
echo $myArray
```

php

```
$ScriptData = shell_exec("sh script.sh");
echo $ScriptData;
# $data = array("Red","Green","Blue");

eval($ScriptData);
print_r($ScriptData);
# Array
# (
#   [0] => Red
#   [1] => Green
#   [2] => Blue
# )
```